# How do I reference a dynamically named control on a UserControl from the Parent Form?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, user-controls

How do I reference a dynamically named control on a UserControl from the Parent Form?  (In Winforms).

I have a single parent form but it may load any 1 of around 20 or so UserControls. We will call them `ucA, ucB, etc`.

Each UserControl has a different number of textboxes, but are named `tbA01, tbA02, etc on ucA and tbB01, tbB02, etc on ucB`.

How would I reference the value of the textboxes?

I cannot seem to reference the name of the UserControl directly.  I know the name of the UserControl as a string, but canot seem to cast it as a control.  Likewise with the textboxes on the UserControl.  I am sure I can use Control.Find() for the name of the textbox from a simple string.  But this doesn't appear to be working, which I assume it will only be looking for controls on ParentForm and not the collection of controls on the UserControl.  I assume there would be a method using TryCast or DirectCast and using the Control.Find() in the arguments.  But I have not found a solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have the UserControls expose public methods or properties that allow anything else that is aware of the UserControl existence, to get or set an internal value (the Text property of a TextBox, for example). The same thing you do with a ComboBox or a ListBox: you don't directly set the Text of the Edit Control of the Items of a ListControl. You use public properties/methods.

Comment: *I cannot seem to reference the name of the UserControl directly*. This is unlikely. You have an instance of the UserControl inside the Form. Did you add the UserControl at run-time? Insert the UCs you build in a `List(Of UserControl)` and use that to reference the UCs or use [Controls.Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find) to retrieve the instance(s).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jimi!  Your answer did help me look at a different method in coming up with a solution.  I have it working now.  Here is what I used:

```
Dim matches() As Control
matches = Me.Controls.Find(TblName, True)
If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
    Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
    ...
Endif
```